# startChildActivity issue when working with TabGroupActivity

Tags: android

Fallowing is Home class. I am going to call Pick_contact intent. When ContactNumber view is clicked, device contact list is shown. And the result of picked contact is getting on TabGroupActivity.

```
public class Home extends Activity{
    private static int PICK_CONTACT= 1;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
    }

public void ContactNumber(View v)
    {
       Intent intent = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
       parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
       parentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }
```

}

My TabGroupActivity code is shown below.

```
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(requestCode == PICK_CONTACT)
        {
             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                 Uri contactData = data.getData();
                 Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                 String cNumber="";
                 if (c.moveToFirst()) {


                     String id =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                     String hasPhone =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                       if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                      Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
                                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, 
                                   null, null);
                         phones.moveToFirst();
                          cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                         System.out.println("number is:"+cNumber);
                       }
                     String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    QRCodeStaticData.qr_contents=name;

                 }

               }
        }
}

}
```

In this above code when user pick up contact from list, I want to open other child activity. But if user does not pick up contact and just cancel it, user will leave on the home activity. I am not getting how to call child activity inside TabGroupActivity after picking contact. I used below code to call child activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), CreateQRCode.class);
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("CreateQRCode", intent);
```

But it does not work inside onActivityResult of TabGroupActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...Sorry for the Late Answer

In your `TabGroupActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    // Adding the Activities to the tab view
    // Blah Blah
}

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        System.out.println("Success");
        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT) {
            //Here you can launch the Child Activity according to the index
            //Here CreateQRCode Activity index is 1 in the TabView
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fail");
    }
}
```

In your `HomeActivity`

```
public void ContactNumber(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But according to your code, if I pick up contact from list, then I will be on my Home activity. But I want to open other child activity inside the home activity. 

Like this:  Home activity ->(If success)-> open other child activity of Home activity else leave me on Home Activity

Comment: Here what do you mean by **child activiy of home activity** ?

Comment: public class HomeTabGroup extends TabGroupActivity {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  QRCodeStaticData.ctx=this;
  startChildActivity("Home",new 
          Intent(this,Home.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
  
 }
}

When I pick up contact, I want to open other activity on getting result which will be the subactivity of home activity. Let it be ResultActivity. In this case ResultActivity is child activity of home Activity.

Comment: I know this is somewhat confusing. If It was simple app, I will do it without any issue. But making app with tabs, it was getting difficult to implement. Because the result of Contacts is getting on TabGroupActivity and not on Home Activity.

Comment: Check the edited one, This will startActivity from the Home, Please override the **onActivityResult** in the HomeActiviy ie, where you are using **startActivityForResult()**